# PhantomJS invalid page render

Tags: phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs on Windows 7 x64 to make my page screenshot. My code is

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("http://localhost/index.html", function start(status) {
  page.render('screeshot.png', {format: 'png', quality: '100'});
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I get screenshot like
[image]

while Chrome 51 show me page like this

[image]

Comment: Please, add page.onError callbacks to check for erros and also some info on the site/HTML would be useful.

Comment: I've added onError handler but it returns nothing

Comment: Every browser is different and most developers don't test their pages for compatibility with PhantomJS. It could be any number of things that is wrong, but it looks like a CSS issue. Write better code and/or update to a newer PhantomJS version.

Answer (score 0):

add a delay, maybe phantomjs haven't load the site completely

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("http://localhost/index.html", function start(status) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  page.render('screeshot.png', {format: 'png', quality: '100'});
  phantom.exit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

or try this script (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) with command line:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://localhost/index.html /yourFolder 1920px
```